# Find free room (booking system)

Tags: mysql

For a booking system I have a table with rooms, arrival and departure.

Example data:

```
id | room | arrival    | departure
---+------+------------+-----------
1  | 1    | 2011-03-12 | 2011-03-14
2  | 1    | 2011-03-08 | 2011-03-09
3  | 1    | 2011-03-19 | 2011-03-20
4  | 2    | 2011-03-22 | 2011-03-30 
5  | 2    | 2011-03-19 | 2011-03-22
```

My question is now: if I have a new booking (`2011-03-10` to `2011-03-12`), how can I check which rooms are free?

Output for this example should be room `1` and `2`.

Comment: Room 3,4 and 5 also seem to be available. (--> you need an extra table, with basically a list of the existing rooms)

Comment: ok u are right.... i still have this table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a query that will show the NOT-FREE rooms for a date span:

```
select room from bookings where
(arrival<'2011-03-12' and departure>='2011-03-12') -- overlap at the end
OR (arrival<='2011-03-10' and departure>'2011-03-10') -- overlap at the start
OR (arrival>='2011-03-10' and departure<='2011-03-12') -- complete overlap
```

You can use this with

```
select roomnumber from rooms where roomnumber not in (... as above ...)
```

to find the FREE rooms

Comment: PERFECT... very nice :) I just added DISTINCT to the first statement

Comment: This could be expanded to select count(*) as num, room from bookingds ... group by room : This way it would tell you the NUMBER of collisions - If your hotel is quite full, a low number of collisions might inidcate the possibility to get away with a room-swap. (Just brainstorming on your DISTINCT)

Comment: I had a very similar problem, and came out with your very solution. Was searching on SO for other ideas, and then laughed when I saw your answer. Exactly what I was doing. Cool :D

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `BETWEEN` comparison operator for this purpose. In this case you would do something like this:

```
SELECT r.id FROM room r WHERE r.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT rb.room FROM room_booking rb WHERE 
        ('2011-03-10' BETWEEN rb.arrival AND rb.departure) OR 
        ('2011-03-12' BETWEEN rb.arrival AND rb.departure)
)
```

Comment: This query will fal to detect complete overlaps: if a room was booked for 2011-03-10 to 2011-03-12, your query for 2011-03-08 to 2011-03-14 would show the room as free, i.e. you only change overlaps on start and end, but not complete overlaps.

Comment: It's true though, I'd do this instead: `('2011-03-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN arrival AND departure AND ('2011-03-12' - INTERVAL 1 DAY) BETWEEN arrival AND departure`