# How to select free rooms for reservations in CodeIgniter - two tables?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I want to select free rooms between dateStart and dateEnd in CodeIgniter.

I have 2 tables - rooms and reservations.

My current model code:

```
$this->db->select('rooms.*');

$this->db->join('reservations', 'rooms.ID = reservations.RoomID', 'left outer');

$this->db->where('rooms.Size >=', $PeopleNumber);
$this->db->where('reservations.DateStart <=', $DateEnd);
$this->db->where('reservations.DateEnd >=', $DateStart);

$this->db->group_by('rooms.Size');

$query = $this->db->get('rooms');
```

I've already checked this question: [MySQL Looking for free rooms in reservation system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366674/mysql-looking-for-free-rooms-in-reservation-system)

but I don't know how to multiselect in CodeIgniter.

My SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c1f95/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i resolved this:

```
$this->db->where('`ID` NOT IN (SELECT `RoomID` FROM `reservations` WHERE `DateStart` < "' .$DateEnd. '" AND `DateEnd` > "' .$DateStart. '")', NULL, FALSE);
```